# Force LinearLayout child to use all available space but at least enough to fit its content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm struggling with getting `LinearLayout` to behave like I want it. Unfortunately, both dimension modes `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` don't seem to fit for my purposes.

Here's why: I want the child that is added to the `LinearLayout` to be completely visible. Nothing should be cut off. So normally, I should use `WRAP_CONTENT` to achieve this behaviour.

But, if there's more space in the `LinearLayout` than the child really needs, I also want it to fill that space. This is of course what `MATCH_PARENT` is for.

However, I can't use `MATCH_PARENT` because in case there is **less** space in the `LinearLayout` than my child needs, using `MATCH_PARENT` will cut off the child which I don't want.

So this leaves me somewhat puzzled as to how I can achieve what I want: How can I allow a child to fill additional space in the `LinearLayout` (if available) while at the same time forcing the `LinearLayout` to be at least as big as the child needs in order to be completely visible?

Comment: did you tried using weights ?

Comment: I don't see how using weights could solve this problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Andreas What you want to achieve? You mean parent layout ellaborate depends on the child view maximum required width or height?.

Answer (score 0):

Put your child view inside a `ScrollView` with width `MATCH_PARENT`, height `MATCH_PARENT`and set both the child's dimensions `MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like a lot of overhead. Isn't there a more efficient solution for my problem?

Comment: What overhead? We're talking about 1 layout, 1 scrollview and 1 view. Overheads may occur for complex layouts

Comment: Well, of course my question is just an illustration. In reality it's much more complicated because I'm working on a whole GUI layout toolkit here. With your solution, I'd have to wrap every single child view inside a `ScrollView` which is a lot of overhead IMHO.

Comment: Yes but you must focus at the fact: *in case there is less space in the LinearLayout than my child needs, using MATCH_PARENT will cut off the child which I don't want* So the only option is to scroll to see the whole view.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's a misunderstanding then. What I mean by *less space* is this: Suppose you have a horizontal layout and the first child is a `ProgressBar` added using `WRAP_CONTENT` as height and the second child is a `Button`. Now if I use `MATCH_PARENT` as height for the button, it will be cut to the height of the `ProgressBar` which is only a few pixels. If I use `WRAP_CONTENT` instead, the layout will be alright for this particular case, but **not** if the first child is not a `ProgressBar` but something that is vertically higher than the button. Then it won't work. See what I mean?

Comment: This is totally  another case. You must use `weightSum` for the layout and `layout_weight` for each of the views, but you have to decide about the proportions. But still I think that you may need the ScrollView

Comment: Some other people have suggested using `layout_weight` too but I still don't think that it is up for the job because weights represent the proportional child size *in the direction of the layout*. Now please read again my description in my previous comment: As you can see, I have a *horizontal layout* but I'm actually concerned about the *height* of the children in that layout. AFAICS, `layout_weight` can only affect the *width* of the children because the layout itself is horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using MATCH_PARENT for your child, use WRAP_CONTENT and set your child's weight to 1,So it will take all the empty space in your LinearLayout. Suppose your LinearLayout's height is 128dp, and your child 's height is 56dp, your child will be 128dp . If you set WRAP_CONTENT on your LinearLayout, it will be 56dp, and it child will still take all the place it needs.
If you want your LinearLayout to have a minimum width or height, and not match_parent, you can do setMinimumWidth() or setMinimumHeight() in your xml layout or in your code programmatycally depending your childs default height and width.

Comment: Please see my last comment to mTak's answer.